# Error importing JQuery plugin with Webpack 2.2.1

Tags: javascript, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I've a simple Symfony/Webpack project that runs great with webpack 2.2.0.
But since updating to 2.2.1, the front side breaks when running project with webpack-dev-server.

You can clone example project : git@gitlab.com:gaea44/symfony-webpack-221.git

Here is how I configured webpack :

```
├── app
|   └── Resources
|       └── assets
|           └── src
|               └── app.js
|── other symfony files
|── package.json
|── webpack.dev.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

Here is my webpack.config.js :

```
context: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/Resources/assets/src'),

entry  : {
    app: './app.js',
},

output : {
    path         : path.resolve(__dirname, './web/build'),
    filename     : '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath   : 'http://localhost:8090/assets/',
},
```

I use babel with es-2015

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    use : [{
      loader : 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets    : ['es2015'],
        retainLines: true,
      }
    }],
},
```

Other Webpack plugin I use are : CommonsChunkPlugin, HotModuleReplacementPlugin, UglifyJsPlugin and DefinePlugin.

I symply import a jQuery plugin inside my app.js file :

```
// Jquery
import 'expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery!jquery';

// Boostrap
import 'bootstrap-sass';

// Other vendor
import 'bootstrap-fileinput';
import 'bootstrap-fileinput/js/locales/fr';

$('[type=file]').fileinput();
```

And the error I get :

[image]

Plugins works fine with webpack 2.2.0 (you can test if with webpack220 branch on the example project)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

add line before bootstrap-fileinput: 

`window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');`